# md5 hash for file without File Attributes

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, hash, md5

Using the following code to compute MD5 hashs of files:

```
 Private _MD5Hash As String
 Dim _BinaryData As Byte() = New Byte(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length) {}
 FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(_BinaryData, 0, _BinaryData.Length)

 Dim md5 As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
 Dim md5hash() As Byte
 md5hash = md5.ComputeHash(Me._BinaryData)
 Me._MD5Hash = ByteArrayToString(md5hash)

  Private Function ByteArrayToString(ByVal arrInput() As Byte) As String
     Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(arrInput.Length * 2)
     For i As Integer = 0 To arrInput.Length - 1
       sb.Append(arrInput(i).ToString("X2"))
     Next
     Return sb.ToString().ToLower
  End Function
```

We are getting different hashes depending on the create-date and modify-date of the file.  We are storing the hash and the binary file in a SQL DB.  This works fine when we upload the same instance of a file.  But when we save a new instance of the file from the DB (with today's date as the create/modify) on the file-system and then check the new hash versus the MD5 stored in the DB they do not match, and therefor fail a duplicate check.

How can we check for a file hash excluding the file attributes? or is there a different issue here?

Comment: Perhaps the document is storing the modification date internally - what type of file is it?

Comment: where is Me._BinaryData getting initialized? What is it getting set to?

Comment: They are .docx, .pdf, .ppt type files.  Nothing too fancy.

Comment: Updated above to include the file's byte()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the ol' VB issue of array declaration.  The size is the UpperBound not then length.

```
Dim _BinaryData As Byte() = New Byte(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length) {}
```

should be:

```
Dim _BinaryData As Byte() = New Byte(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length - 1 ) {}
```

Every file had an extra empty byte at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `Me._BinaryData` is getting initialized with more than just the contents of the file...

Ultimately the only way the hash can change is if the byte array changes.

Another possibility is character set / encoding differences when you persist/restore the file from the DB.